# How to index a two column database in AWS (DynamoDB or SQL) for preformance

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I want an efficient way to store ItemIDs and AttributeIDs for querying in DynamoDb.

There are a few thousand unique ItemIDs and 300 unique AttributeIDs.
Each ItemID is usually associated with 20-100 AttributeIDs.
Each AttributeID is associated with 20,000-40,000 ItemIDs
There will be more AttributeIDs added with time.

I would like to be able to query to find:

1. Return me the AttributeIDs associated with a given ItemID
2. Find me the ItemIDs associated with a given AttributeID

My initial solutions are

1. DynamoDB: Have a table where one ItemID matches an AttributeID. The primary key will be a Hash and Rage where the Hash = ItemID and Range = AttributeID. Have a global secondary index, Hash and Range where Hash= AttributeID and Range = ItemID.
2. Same thing as above but with SQL, though this will result in about 9 million entries which will be slow for performance, especially as I add more AttributeIDs.

Is my solution okay or what is a better way of doing it? With the way I'm suggesting, would there be any difference in performance between an SQL and DynamoDB version (due to underlying table implementations)?

Comment: Not sure why you say there is a difference between DynamoDB and SQL

Comment: Don't know if there would be a difference in performance. So there wouldn't be a difference in performance with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have

1. table `Item` with index on `ItemID`
2. table `Atribute` with index on `AtributeID`
3. table `Item Atribute` with two fields `ItemID, AtributeID` with a composite index with both field.

And 9 millions is nothing for a db. Using the index you will find atributes for each item in milliseconds.

Comment: Would there be any advantage of using DynamoDB over RDS?

Comment: Maybe this other [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966368/aws-mysql-rds-vs-aws-dynamodb) help

Comment: With DynamoDB, what benefit would the two tables have over having a primary hash and range key with ItemID and AttributeID respectively, and a global secondary index with AttributeID and ItemID as hash and range respectively?